# Breakpoint handling in another process

Tags: c++, debugging, winapi, assembly

Following advices given in [Read eax register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16490906/read-eax-register/) , I wrote a simple debugger using winapi.
My objective is to read the eax register each time after an assembly instruction is executed in another thread.
It is working and I managed to put an hardware breakpoint in another process.

The problem arise when the breakpoint is reach inside the debuggee thread, I can read the eax register as intended, but I still couldn't find any way to resume the thread's execution.

My code :

```
 int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
 {
 // Finding Window
HWND window = FindWindow(0, _T("Test"));
if( window == 0 )
{
    printf("Process not found!\n");
    return 0;
}

DWORD_PTR pID = 0;
GetWindowThreadProcessId(window, &pID);


// Get Handle
//HANDLE _handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pID);

DWORD_PTR eax = 0;
DWORD_PTR address = 0xC31E1B; // address of the instruction after the call for hardware breakpoint

DebugActiveProcess(pID); // PID of target process

// Avoid killing app on exit
DebugSetProcessKillOnExit(false);

// get thread ID of the main thread in process
DWORD_PTR dwThreadID = GetProcessThreadID(pID);

// gain access to the thread
HANDLE hThread = OpenThread(THREAD_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, dwThreadID);

SetDebugPrivilege(true);

//ctx.Dr6=0;           //clear debug status register (only bits 0-3 of dr6 are cleared by processor)

CONTEXT ctx = {0};
ctx.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_DEBUG_REGISTERS | CONTEXT_INTEGER;
ctx.Dr0 = address;
ctx.Dr7 = 0x00000001;


// hThread with enough permissions
SetThreadContext(hThread, &ctx); 

DEBUG_EVENT dbgEvent;
while (true)
{
    if (WaitForDebugEvent(&dbgEvent, INFINITE) == 0)
        break;

    if (dbgEvent.dwDebugEventCode == EXCEPTION_DEBUG_EVENT &&
        dbgEvent.u.Exception.ExceptionRecord.ExceptionCode == EXCEPTION_SINGLE_STEP) // EXCEPTION_BREAKPOINT
    {
        if (dbgEvent.u.Exception.ExceptionRecord.ExceptionAddress == (LPVOID)address)
        {
            GetThreadContext(hThread, &ctx);
            eax = ctx.Eax; // eax get
            std::cout<<eax<<"\n";
            // Resume execution
            ctx.Eip = address + 0x3;
            SetThreadContext(hThread, &ctx);
        }

    }

    ContinueDebugEvent(dbgEvent.dwProcessId, dbgEvent.dwThreadId, DBG_CONTINUE);
}
return 0;
}
```

Thanks for help !!

Comment: For a breakpoint you usually use int 3, which is only one byte, so (at least at first glance) adding 3 to EIP looks wrong. Also, that int 3 usually overwrites an existing byte, so you normally restore the existing byte, set the single-step flag, execute one instruction, re-set the int 3 in that byte, and clear the single step flag.

Comment: He uses hardware breakpoints, so I think there is nothing to restore.

Comment: @alkapone did you manage to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Taken from this: [Hardware breakpoints EXCEPTION_SINGLE_STEP all the time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29287507/hardware-breakpoints-exception-single-step-all-the-time)

The entire logic should be following:

1. Add breakpoint.
2. Upon triggering it, you remove the breakpoint and set a Single Step flag in EFLAGS (0x100)
3. The next time the loop is called, you re-enable the hardware breakpoint.

So your while-loop should be like this:

```
while (true)
{
    if (WaitForDebugEvent(&dbgEvent, INFINITE) == 0)
        break;

    if (dbgEvent.dwDebugEventCode == EXCEPTION_DEBUG_EVENT &&
        dbgEvent.u.Exception.ExceptionRecord.ExceptionCode == EXCEPTION_SINGLE_STEP) // EXCEPTION_BREAKPOINT
    {
        CONTEXT newCtx = {0};
        newCtx.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_ALL;
        GetThreadContext(hThread, &newCtx);
        if (dbgEvent.u.Exception.ExceptionRecord.ExceptionAddress == (LPVOID)address)
        {
            newCtx.Dr0 = newCtx.Dr6 = newCtx.Dr7 = 0;
            newCtx.EFlags |= (1 << 8);
        }else{
            newCtx.Dr0 = address;
            newCtx.Dr7 = 0x00000001;
            newCtx.EFlags &= ~(1 << 8);
        }
        SetThreadContext(hThread, &newCtx);
    }
    ContinueDebugEvent(dbgEvent.dwProcessId, dbgEvent.dwThreadId, DBG_CONTINUE);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (dbgEvent.dwDebugEventCode == EXCEPTION_DEBUG_EVENT &&
    dbgEvent.u.Exception.ExceptionRecord.ExceptionCode == EXCEPTION_SINGLE_STEP) // EXCEPTION_BREAKPOINT
{
    if (dbgEvent.u.Exception.ExceptionRecord.ExceptionAddress == (LPVOID)address)
    {
        GetThreadContext(hThread, &ctx);
        std::cout << ctx.Eax << "\n";
        ctx.Dr7 = 0;
        SetThreadContext(hThread, &ctx);
    }
}
```

Disabling Dr0 in Dr7 in ctx should do the job. The other comments don't fix the issue)

Comment: Hey, thank you for the answer, I want to accept it but I don't remember exactly how I fixed this issue 8 years ago haha. Maybe you can copy paste the whole working code here and then I'll accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

[ContinueDebugEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windows/desktop/ms679285(v=vs.85).aspx)(dwProcessId, dwThreadId, dwContinueStatus)

---

This should do the job! you don't need to change eip. if you want more information read [Writing the Debugger's Main Loop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windows/desktop/ms681675(v=vs.85).aspx)