# Automatically a debug process from C# code and read register values

Tags: c#, windows, debugging, winapi, process

I'm looking for a way to read the edx registry at a certain address like asked in this question: [Read eax register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16490906/read-eax-register/)

Although my solution needs to be in C# and I tried to make it, what I got at this moment is:

```
public static IntPtr GetEdx(IntPtr address, Process process)
    {
        const uint DBG_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED = 0x80010001;
        const uint EXCEPTION_SINGLE_STEP = 0x80000004;
        const int DBG_CONTINUE = 0x00010002; // Seems to work better than DBG_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED

        //DebugSetProcessKillOnExit(0);
        DEBUG_EVENT evt = new DEBUG_EVENT();
        // Attach to the process we provided the thread as an argument
        if (!DebugActiveProcess(process.Id))
            throw new Win32Exception();

        CONTEXT context = new CONTEXT();

        foreach (ProcessThread thread in process.Threads)
        {
            uint iThreadId = (uint)thread.Id;
            IntPtr hThread =
                OpenThread(
                    ThreadAccessFlags.SUSPEND_RESUME | ThreadAccessFlags.SET_CONTEXT |
                    ThreadAccessFlags.GET_CONTEXT, false, iThreadId);

            // Suspent the thread
            if (SuspendThread(hThread) == -1) throw new ApplicationException("Cannot suspend thread.");

            context = new CONTEXT
            {
                ContextFlags = (uint)CONTEXT_FLAGS.CONTEXT_DEBUG_REGISTERS |
                               (uint)CONTEXT_FLAGS.CONTEXT_INTEGER
            };

            // Get the context
            if (!GetThreadContext(hThread, ref context))
                throw new Win32Exception();

            // Change the context

            context.Dr0 = (uint)address;
            context.Dr7 = 0x00000001;

            // Set the changed context back
            if (!SetThreadContext(hThread, ref context))
                throw new Win32Exception();

            // Check if setting the context give any errors
            var error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            if (error != 0)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("Error is setting context.");
            }

            // Resume the thread
            if (ResumeThread(hThread) == -1) throw new ApplicationException("Cannot resume thread.");
        }

        while (true)
        {
            if (!WaitForDebugEvent(out evt, -1))
                throw new Win32Exception();

            // Multiple if's for easier debugging at this moment
            if (evt.dwDebugEventCode == (uint)DebugEventType.EXCEPTION_DEBUG_EVENT)
            {
                if (evt.Exception.ExceptionRecord.ExceptionCode == EXCEPTION_SINGLE_STEP)
                {
                    if (evt.Exception.ExceptionRecord.ExceptionAddress == address)
                    {
                        context = new CONTEXT
                        {
                            ContextFlags = (uint)CONTEXT_FLAGS.CONTEXT_DEBUG_REGISTERS |
                                           (uint)CONTEXT_FLAGS.CONTEXT_INTEGER
                        };
                        GetThreadContext((IntPtr)evt.dwThreadId, ref context);
                        return (IntPtr)context.Ebx; // ebx get
                    }
                }
            }

            ContinueDebugEvent(evt.dwProcessId, evt.dwThreadId, DBG_CONTINUE);//DBG_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED);
        }
    }
```

With a whole lot of Kernel32 methods:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern int ResumeThread(IntPtr hThread);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern uint SuspendThread(IntPtr hThread);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr OpenThread(ThreadAccessFlags dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, uint dwThreadId);
    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool DebugActiveProcess(int dwProcessId);
    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool WaitForDebugEvent([Out] out DEBUG_EVENT lpDebugEvent, int dwMilliseconds);
    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool ContinueDebugEvent(int dwProcessId, int dwThreadId, uint dwContinueStatus);
    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool IsDebuggerPresent();
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern bool GetThreadContext(IntPtr hThread, ref CONTEXT lpContext);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern bool SetThreadContext(IntPtr hThread, ref CONTEXT lpContext);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public unsafe struct DEBUG_EVENT
    {
        public readonly uint dwDebugEventCode;
        public readonly int dwProcessId;
        public readonly int dwThreadId;


        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 86, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.U1)]
        private readonly byte[] debugInfo;


        public EXCEPTION_DEBUG_INFO Exception
        {
            get
            {
                if (debugInfo == null)
                    return new EXCEPTION_DEBUG_INFO();


                fixed (byte* ptr = debugInfo)
                {
                    return *(EXCEPTION_DEBUG_INFO*)ptr;
                }
            }
        }


        public LOAD_DLL_DEBUG_INFO LoadDll
        {
            get
            {
                if (debugInfo == null)
                    return new LOAD_DLL_DEBUG_INFO();


                fixed (byte* ptr = debugInfo)
                {
                    return *(LOAD_DLL_DEBUG_INFO*)ptr;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct LOAD_DLL_DEBUG_INFO
    {
        public readonly IntPtr hFile;
        public readonly IntPtr lpBaseOfDll;
        public readonly uint dwDebugInfoFileOffset;
        public readonly uint nDebugInfoSize;
        public readonly IntPtr lpImageName;
        public readonly ushort fUnicode;
    }


    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct EXCEPTION_DEBUG_INFO
    {
        public EXCEPTION_RECORD ExceptionRecord;
        public readonly uint dwFirstChance;
    }


    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct EXCEPTION_RECORD
    {
        public readonly uint ExceptionCode;
        public readonly uint ExceptionFlags;
        public readonly IntPtr ExceptionRecord;
        public readonly IntPtr ExceptionAddress;
        public readonly uint NumberParameters;


        //[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 15, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.U4)]
        //public readonly uint[] ExceptionInformation;


        public unsafe fixed uint ExceptionInformation[15];
    }


    public enum DebugEventType : int
    {
        CREATE_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT = 3, //Reports a create-process debugging event. The value of u.CreateProcessInfo specifies a CREATE_PROCESS_DEBUG_INFO structure.
        CREATE_THREAD_DEBUG_EVENT = 2, //Reports a create-thread debugging event. The value of u.CreateThread specifies a CREATE_THREAD_DEBUG_INFO structure.
        EXCEPTION_DEBUG_EVENT = 1, //Reports an exception debugging event. The value of u.Exception specifies an EXCEPTION_DEBUG_INFO structure.
        EXIT_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT = 5, //Reports an exit-process debugging event. The value of u.ExitProcess specifies an EXIT_PROCESS_DEBUG_INFO structure.
        EXIT_THREAD_DEBUG_EVENT = 4, //Reports an exit-thread debugging event. The value of u.ExitThread specifies an EXIT_THREAD_DEBUG_INFO structure.
        LOAD_DLL_DEBUG_EVENT = 6, //Reports a load-dynamic-link-library (DLL) debugging event. The value of u.LoadDll specifies a LOAD_DLL_DEBUG_INFO structure.
        OUTPUT_DEBUG_STRING_EVENT = 8, //Reports an output-debugging-string debugging event. The value of u.DebugString specifies an OUTPUT_DEBUG_STRING_INFO structure.
        RIP_EVENT = 9, //Reports a RIP-debugging event (system debugging error). The value of u.RipInfo specifies a RIP_INFO structure.
        UNLOAD_DLL_DEBUG_EVENT = 7, //Reports an unload-DLL debugging event. The value of u.UnloadDll specifies an UNLOAD_DLL_DEBUG_INFO structure.
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct CONTEXT
    {
        public uint ContextFlags;
        public uint Dr0;
        public uint Dr1;
        public uint Dr2;
        public uint Dr3;
        public uint Dr6;
        public uint Dr7;
        public FLOATING_SAVE_AREA FloatSave;
        public uint SegGs;
        public uint SegFs;
        public uint SegEs;
        public uint SegDs;
        public uint Edi;
        public uint Esi;
        public uint Ebx;
        public uint Edx;
        public uint Ecx;
        public uint Eax;
        public uint Ebp;
        public uint Eip;
        public uint SegCs;
        public uint EFlags;
        public uint Esp;
        public uint SegSs;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 512)]
        public byte[] ExtendedRegisters;
    }

    public enum CONTEXT_FLAGS : uint
    {
        CONTEXT_i386 = 0x10000,
        CONTEXT_i486 = 0x10000,
        CONTEXT_CONTROL = CONTEXT_i386 | 0x01,
        CONTEXT_INTEGER = CONTEXT_i386 | 0x02,
        CONTEXT_SEGMENTS = CONTEXT_i386 | 0x04,
        CONTEXT_FLOATING_POINT = CONTEXT_i386 | 0x08,
        CONTEXT_DEBUG_REGISTERS = CONTEXT_i386 | 0x10,
        CONTEXT_EXTENDED_REGISTERS = CONTEXT_i386 | 0x20,
        CONTEXT_FULL = CONTEXT_CONTROL | CONTEXT_INTEGER | CONTEXT_SEGMENTS,
        CONTEXT_ALL = CONTEXT_CONTROL | CONTEXT_INTEGER | CONTEXT_SEGMENTS | CONTEXT_FLOATING_POINT | CONTEXT_DEBUG_REGISTERS | CONTEXT_EXTENDED_REGISTERS
    }

    [Flags]
    public enum ThreadAccessFlags : int
    {
        TERMINATE = 0x0001,
        SUSPEND_RESUME = 0x0002,
        GET_CONTEXT = 0x0008,
        SET_CONTEXT = 0x0010,
        SET_INFORMATION = 0x0020,
        QUERY_INFORMATION = 0x0040,
        SET_THREAD_TOKEN = 0x0080,
        IMPERSONATE = 0x0100,
        DIRECT_IMPERSONATION = 0x0200
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct FLOATING_SAVE_AREA
    {
        public uint ControlWord;
        public uint StatusWord;
        public uint TagWord;
        public uint ErrorOffset;
        public uint ErrorSelector;
        public uint DataOffset;
        public uint DataSelector;

        // missing some stuff
        public uint Cr0NpxState;
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern int VirtualQueryEx(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpAddress, out MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION lpBuffer, int dwLength);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, int lpBaseAddress, byte[] buffer, int size,
        int lpNumberOfBytesRead);
```

But for some reason it never hits the `evt.Exception.ExceptionRecord.ExceptionAddress == address`

I'm pretty new to memory reading and have a hard time figuring out what is wrong with the code above.

EDIT: Also if I uncomment the `context.Dr7 = 0x00000001;` the application that I'm trying to read crashes.

Comment: It's tricky to tell without more information - what's the nature of the program you're trying to debug and how have you determined the correct value for the `address` parameter?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever The program itself is a singleplayer game in C++. And I know the correct values because of the use of Cheat Engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The theory**:

You want to attach to a process, put a breakpoint in it, register an event in the debugger application and wait for that event. You need to put the breakpoint at the address you give as parameter, and by reading the context you should be able to see the content of EDX. This seems reasonable, like a human developer would do it.

**The implementation:**

Looking at your implementation, the method you try to use to put the breakpoint at the address seems suspicious. Reading **[here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680632%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)** I understand that trying to set the context on a running thread might give unpredictable results. You may also lack the sufficient permissions. Assuming you have the permissions, **try stopping the threads before setting the context**.

The other problem I predict is that **the thread you want to stop and debug has a context that needs to be altered as less as possible**. I think that you should first stop the thread, read it's context, change the Dr0 flag (*assuming that's where you set the breakpoint*) and then set the context with all the other register information unaltered.

Without that, I think that you basically change the execution of the program and *I have a strong feeling that some of those registers are read only*.

These are 2 things you need to consider. Hope it helps.

**Debugging:**

If that does not work, you need to **add a function that uses GetLastError()** to see why the functions fail (I'm suspecting SetThreadContext() will be the one causing problems in the first time).

You must also check that the Context structure is defined correctly and **all the members have the same order has the ones defined** **[here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679284(v=vs.85).aspx)**. The structure has to be aligned by the C# code exactly as in the unmanaged code.

Also please check if you are running on a 64bit OS. The context of a thread in a 64bit OS is different than for 32bit. Registers are extended for 64b and so on. **If you use a 64bit OS, the context structure needs to be redefined**. Same goes if you use an ARM machine.

Comment: thanks for your very clear response. I'm on my way home and I'll read up on what you said and try to change my code.

Comment: I've changed the code to `Suspend` and `Resume` the thread. The Dr0 is indeed the address I'm trying to read from but even with the current changes it will never hit the `evt.Exception.ExceptionRecord.ExceptionAddress == address`.

Comment: The even bigger problem is that you don't copy the thread's context, alter it and then set the altered one as the new context. You need to do that also.

Comment: I added more info to the post at the end.

Comment: To answer your comment earlier, I do get the Context now, then suspend, then edit, then set the context and then resume the context. I used `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();` and the error was 87. According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx this means incorret parameter. (this is with the `context.Dr7 = 0x00000001;` commented out. If I uncomment the `context.Dr7 = 0x00000001;` there is no error (0). But the application I'm setting breakpoints in crashes then.

Comment: Added some more suggestions.

Comment: Yeah I got the problem, it was that because the single player game is a steam game it flags some thread as 'hidden' and because I won't be able to catch the exception then the game crashes. I've fixed that, the only problem left is that the 'edx' of the GetThreadContext is 0. Maybe this is indeed because I'm running on x64 bit machine. I'll try to find a 64 bit context structure.

Comment: That should be in you WinNT.h file on your system. Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

Your answer seems to be hiding in one of the comments you transplanted with the other code... The functions to set and get thread context require a handle to a thread (probably opened with OpenThread using appropriate permissions, including at least get/set context).  Instead, you're apparently passing a casted process ID.  You should consider checking the return value for success, it would've probably helped identify your problem.

Comment: You can see the original code if you look at the linked question. There is no missing code as far as the example goes in the linked question. Also I check the return values and all of them give a 'true' except for the if statement `evt.Exception.ExceptionRecord.ExceptionCode ==  EXCEPTION_SINGLE_STEP`

Comment: Ah you are talking about the `SetThreadContext` and indeed that does return `false`. And it's not like 'HELP, WRITE A DEBUGGER FOR ME!' I did my own research but I'm not getting any further. And without big knowledge of the win32 api or it's methods I'm just asking what would be wrong with the code above. But I'll look into what could be wrong with the `SetThreadContext` method.

Comment: Why even bother, when Mike Stall's excellent Microsoft.Samples.Debugging package [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2006/07/05/managed-wrappers-for-native-debug-api.aspx) can be had on NuGet and includes a wrapper for the native debugging API?