# How to find which thread will execute an instruction?

Tags: c++, debugging, winapi, assembly, x86

I'm very surprised this hasn't been asked before. I'm trying to put a breakpoint on a specific instruction and read the registers in an already running process (Following this post: [Read eax register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16490906/read-eax-register/)).

I found the instruction I'm looking for, however the problem I've been running into is how do I find the right thread where the instruction is going to be executed, so I can do `SetThreadContext()` on it. This is a multithreaded program, so its not as simple as looking up for the single thread that is associated with the process.

I tried looking through Cheat Engine's source to see how they did it, however I couldn't find much, so I'm wondering how exactly they did it.

One idea that comes to mind is just setting every thread's context to it, however I'd like to avoid that.

EDIT: Forgot to mention I'm trying to do this with hardware breakpoints (using debug registers)

Comment: There isn't in general any way to look at a thread and predict what it will do in the future - that's the halting problem, even if its behavior doesn't depend on external inputs.  Normally you'd set the breakpoint in every thread.  If you set it as a software breakpoint by overwriting the instruction with `int3` or the like, then it will automatically affect all threads since they share code memory.

Comment: @NateEldredge: I think the question is asking how to find which thread triggered a breakpoint.  (Because if you put a breakpoint on an instruction, it triggers before the instruction actually executes, the the querent wants to read or modify that thread's registers before the instruction executes.).  I'm trying to think of a clearer title, because my initial reading of the title matched yours.  (Update: the first sentence of this comment would work, using that.)

Comment: An instruction doesn't belong to **any** thread. It's just there in memory, waiting for an execution context to run over it. I don't see what `SetThreadContext` has to do with breakpoints. Just set a `0xcc` byte at the instruction address or set the debug registers (of **all** the threads contexts). To know which thread stepped on the breakpoint, just look at their context. One or more have an instruction pointer inside your handler.

Comment: @MargaretBloom If you read the post I linked, the answer creates a CONTEXT, and sets Dr0 to the instruction address (and Dr7 to utilize Dr0) and uses `SetThreadContext()` to have a thread use the register values. I'm trying not to use software breakpoints as to not overwrite the instruction. This is why I mentioned Cheat Engine, as they also have an option for hardware breakpoints.

Comment: Oh, so I did misinterpret your question when I retitled it?  If you want hardware breakpoints to work, *all* threads that might run this instruction need a hardware breakpoint, so any thread that reaches it will break.  Unless you can predict the future and know which thread to set a HW breakpoint in.

Comment: @PeterCordes I didn't realize how badly I wrote the title lol, my apologies. That's what I was thinking originally but was wondering if that's the only option.

Comment: @inconspicuoususername If you read my comment you see that I wrote *exactly* what Peter wrote. And yes, that's the only option :)

Answer (score 2):

Unless you already know the answer / can predict the future, you need to set a hardware breakpoint *in every thread that might run the instruction you care about*.

The debug registers are per-core (and thus per-thread with context-switching), so a core will only actually break if the thread it's executing has *its* debug registers set to break on that instruction.

It might be easier to use a software breakpoint (`0xcc` byte replacing the first byte of the instruction) because you just have to store that once and every thread will see it.  (x86 has coherent instruction caches; you don't have to invalidate them.)

---

[As Margaret points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68412728/how-to-find-which-thread-will-execute-an-instruction#comment120906903_68412728), once your breakpoint handler runs, you check the EIP / RIP of every thread, and the ones that are currently at that instruction are the one(s) that have reached the breakpoint and will run that instruction if single-stepped or resumed.   (Or an address in your handler, if the handler runs in the context of that thread.)