# Programmatically Setting Breakpoints on Multi-threaded 64-bit Applications

Tags: c++, debugging, reverse-engineering, breakpoints, cpu-registers

I have adapted some code from other sources (primarily [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16490906/read-eax-register/)) and had no avail in my circumstance. I am attaching to a 64-bit application that has upwards of 100 threads at any given time. There are two issues I have, somewhat unrelated:

1. Whenever the code hits `DebugActiveProcess(pid)`, the attached application freezes.
2. The code I have only sets a breakpoint on the main thread, but I need it on more than one - ideally all.

I have confirmed that when the code hits `SetThreadContext(hThread, &ctx)` the `dr0` and `dr7` registers change as intended, so that much is fine. **The only issues I can see right now are the process freezing and setting more than one breakpoint** (I thought of iterating for every single thread which would be fine one-time, but when it gets into the while loop that would obviously be problematic and very resource-consuming). I should also note that I can attach the CheatEngine debugger to the application, and breakpoints work fine with no issues. Below is the code I'm using:

```
DWORD GetProcessThreadID(DWORD dwProcessID)
{
    THREADENTRY32 te = { sizeof(THREADENTRY32) };
    HANDLE hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD, 0);

    if (Thread32First(hSnapshot, &te))
        while (Thread32Next(hSnapshot, &te))
            if (te.th32OwnerProcessID == dwProcessID)
                return te.th32ThreadID;

    return NULL;
}

BOOL SetDebugPrivilege(BOOL State)
{
    HANDLE hToken;
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES token_privileges;
    DWORD dwSize;

    ZeroMemory(&token_privileges, sizeof(token_privileges));
    token_privileges.PrivilegeCount = 1;

    if (!OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS, &hToken))
        return FALSE;

    if (!LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, SE_DEBUG_NAME, &token_privileges.Privileges[0].Luid))
    {
        CloseHandle(hToken);
        return FALSE;
    }

    if (State)
        token_privileges.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
    else
        token_privileges.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_REMOVED;

    if (!AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &token_privileges, 0, NULL, &dwSize))
    {
        CloseHandle(hToken);
        return FALSE;
    }

    return CloseHandle(hToken);
}

void CreateBreakpoint(DWORD pid, DWORD64 addr) {

    DebugActiveProcess(pid);
    DebugSetProcessKillOnExit(false);

    DWORD_PTR dwThreadID = GetProcessThreadID(pid);
    std::cout << std::hex << dwThreadID << std::endl;

    HANDLE hThread = OpenThread(THREAD_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, dwThreadID);

    SetDebugPrivilege(true);

    CONTEXT ctx = { 0 };
    ctx.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_DEBUG_REGISTERS | CONTEXT_INTEGER;
    ctx.Dr0 = addr;
    ctx.Dr7 = 0x00000001;

    SetThreadContext(hThread, &ctx);

    DEBUG_EVENT dbgEvent;
    while (true) {
        if (WaitForDebugEvent(&dbgEvent, INFINITE) == 0)
            break;

        if (dbgEvent.dwDebugEventCode == EXCEPTION_DEBUG_EVENT &&
            dbgEvent.u.Exception.ExceptionRecord.ExceptionCode == EXCEPTION_SINGLE_STEP) // EXCEPTION_BREAKPOINT
        {
            if (dbgEvent.u.Exception.ExceptionRecord.ExceptionAddress == (LPVOID)addr)
            {
                GetThreadContext(hThread, &ctx);
                std::cout << ctx.Rax << "\n";
                ctx.Dr7 = 0;
                SetThreadContext(hThread, &ctx);
            }
        }
        ContinueDebugEvent(dbgEvent.dwProcessId, dbgEvent.dwThreadId, DBG_CONTINUE);
    }
}
```

It may be worth noting that this is a C++ extension to a python script, but that shouldn't really be relevant, and even if I run the code standalone it runs into the same issues. Also, I'm not an expert in C++ so I apologize if there are any misunderstandings.

Comment: Have you tried a real debugger instead of cheat engine? It should break regardless of the thread as long as that thread hits that code, if you do it in the debugger instead of with whatever frankenmonster you’re trying to cook up.

Comment: @Taekahn haha, the reason I'm using breakpoints in the first place is because I'm trying to read a RAX value at an instruction (which is what the address points to) WITHIN a program, for that program to be used. CheatEngine had no issues was kind of my point, and gdb works more or less as intended. If it'll break regardless of thread, then I guess the second issue I listed is moot, but there's still the issue of DebugActiveProcess freezing the debugged application, which I suppose is your point of me cooking up a "frankenmonster".

Comment: I know the ui is hideous, but gdb should be up to that task. I can’t speak to cheat engine as I’ve never used it. I suppose there are other alternatives that might be better such as ida, ghidra, etc.

Comment: As far as I can tell gdb is just a CLI application - is there any way to execute gdb commands programmatically from within C++? I need the register values accessible to the program in runtime.

Comment: Oh. I follow now. I didn’t pick up that last bit. My bad. I believe the answer is actually still yes, because you can call command line programs from within c++ and get their output. I’m not sure if that is better or worse than the current path you’re on though. A side note that might be useful, gdb supports python script extensions.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Taekahn, unless you give more information on what you are trying to do, why not use a normal debugger? if you just want to read the registers, any debugger can do that. You can even set breakpoints in disassembly or random addresses, or set data breakpoints.
IDK about gdb, but even in visual studio you can set conditions and actions on breakpoints. It's not as powerfull as c++ code but again, without more informations...

If you want to modify the behavior of the application, that's not how we do it, and using a debugger can actually cause issues.

Comment: I'm writing a program that randomizes enemies in a video game and the RAX register at a certain instruction pertains to the enemy type. It would be as simple as assigning a random value to the address or changing asm, however some of the enemies/NPCs should not be randomized otherwise player progression could/would be halted, so I need to compare RAX. That is the reason I need to access the RAX register in runtime programmatically. The reason I don't want to use gdb is because then end-user, who should be assumed to be oblivious to how anything works on CLIs, would be required to use gdb.